# EF Core store Images

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In previous versions of EF one was able to store images as a byte array and retrieve them using the System.Drawing namespace. Is there a equivalent to the System.Drawing namespace in EF Core or is this a feature that has not been implemented yet?

Comment: What do you want to do with the image? Rendering it will require an app model, but .NET Core only supports Console. If you're consuming your .NET Standard library in UWP, WinForms, or WPF, convert the bytes to an image there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prototype of `System.Drawing` for .NET Core in [github.com/akoeplinger/mono-winforms-netcore](https://github.com/akoeplinger/mono-winforms-netcore).

`System.Drawing` will also be part of [.NET Standard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard2.0.md)

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using Azure Blob Storage for our application and using the Azure Storage Emulator for local use. We saved and retrieved them from those locations instead of byte arrays.